# how to write long mysql queries in spring mvc in Dao layer

Tags: java, mysql, spring

So I have been trying implement a sql query in my spring mvc project to insert data into the database. The query is working in the mysql workbench. but its giving me an error when i am writing same query in DAO layer in spring project.
error i'm getting is below

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar 
[insert into question (question_id,questions,question_text,user_id) SELECT(?,?,?,?) from user 'where user_id ='2]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''where user_id ='2' at line 1
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:239)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1541)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1015)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1025)
at qnaapp.dao.UserDaoImpl.question(UserDaoImpl.java:44)
at qnaapp.service.UserServiceImpl.question(UserServiceImpl.java:27)
at qnaapp.UserServiceTest1.testQuestion(UserServiceTest1.java:45)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

here is the link of text file of table creation and query
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C966vW9GNs9MFtEheCr2dhs8rztAROaw/view?usp=sharing

here is part of code in DAO layer

```
 public int question(Question question) {
        String sql = "insert into question (question_id,questions,question_text,user_id) 
 SELECT(?,?,?,?) from user "
                    + "'where user_id ='" +question.getUser_id();

    return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] { question.getQuestion_id(),question.getQuestions(), question.getQuestion_text(), question.getUser_id()});
}
```

Edits:
here the junit test class I have been using to test that query
package qnaapp;

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;


import qnaapp.model.Login;
import qnaapp.model.User;
import qnaapp.model.Question;
import qnaapp.service.UserService;


 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:qna/config/user-beans.xml" })
public class UserServiceTest1 {
 @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

 @Test
  public void testValidateUser() {
    Login login = new Login();
    login.setUsername("krishnadubey");
    login.setPassword("123456789");

    User user = userService.validateUser(login);
    Assert.assertEquals("Krishna", user.getFirstname());
  }

  @Test
  public void testQuestion() {
    //User user = new User();
    Question question = new Question();
    question.setQuestion_id(4);
    
    question.setQuestions("Who is founder of c?");
    question.setQuestion_text("Please Explain");
    question.setUser_id(2);
  

    int result = userService.question(question);
    Assert.assertEquals(1, result);
  }
}
```

Please suggest some solution for these problem.

Comment: `SELECT(?,?,?,?) from user 'where user_id ='2` doesn't seem valid SQL synthax

Comment: hey @fantaghirocco so the question mark is where i am going to have the values that are need to be inserted. the my sql query is like this- 

     insert into question ( question_id, questions, question_text, user_id)
SELECT 1 as question_id, "What is java" as questions, "Please Explain in details" as question_text, user_id
FROM user where user_id = 3 ;

you can see it in the drive file.

Comment: the Murenik answers explains what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your sql writing, try the following way of writing：
Be careful not to have extra quotes `'` and parentheses `()`

```java
 public int question(Question question) {
        String sql = "insert into question (question_id,questions,question_text,user_id) 
 SELECT ?,?,?,? from user where user_id =" +question.getUser_id();

    return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] { question.getQuestion_id(),question.getQuestions(), question.getQuestion_text(), question.getUser_id()});
}
```

Comment: Hey @RuneMage thanks for the solution it worked. Can you please write another query. I have Mysql query its working there but i am not able to do it for spring ---- 

insert into answer ( answer_id,answer_text,question_id,user_id)
SELECT 2 as answer_id,
       "Its part of spring mvc" as answer_text,
      question_id,
 us.user_id
FROM question,user as us
where question.question_id = 3 and us.user_id=4;

Comment: @Super MCU Similar to the above writing, you can try this writing. Also note: escape quotes `"`     :

`String sql1 = "insert into answer ( answer_id,answer_text,question_id,user_id) SELECT 2 as answer_id, \"Its part of spring mvc\" as answer_text, question_id, us.user_id FROM question,user as us where question.question_id = "+question.getQuestion_id() + " and us.user_id= " + question.getUser_id();`

Comment: public int answer(Answer answer) {String sql = "insert into answer (answer_id,answer_text,question_id,user_id) SELECT answer_id,answer_text,question_id,us.user_id FROM question,user as us where question.question_id ="+answer.getQuestion_id()+ " and us.user_id= " +answer.getUser_id();
return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] { answer.getAnswer_id(), answer.getAnswer_text(), answer.getQuestion_id(),answer.getUser_id()});
 }
}
i have tried the above query in spring mvc but still giving me an error. I tried to change the question.getQuestion_id still didnt worked. Can you please check

Comment: It is best to post all the error messages. In addition, this is the [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html) of jdbcTemplate.